# Can I configure Putty to Use PC/Mac Copy/Paste Convention?

Tags: terminal, putty, copy-paste

My question is in the title, but let me forestall two responses:

1. Yes, I understand how copy/paste works usually under X.  I spend most of my day working on a Linux workstation.  But my fingers have just become hard-wired to select with the mouse and to copy/paste using the keyboard.  Perhaps the X way is superior in general, but please indulge me.  Also, it is really annoying how often just clicking a window to make sure it is active will create a selection and clobber my clipboard.
2. Yes, I understand that in a terminal application keystrokes like ctrl-C already have a fixed meaning and changing it to do copy would be a bad idea.  But, for example, GNOME Terminal allows me to copy/paste using shift-ctrl-C and shift-ctrl-V and after a little adjustment, I was perfectly content with that.  Even some X servers can apparently be configured that way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305190/how-to-change-the-default-shortcuts-for-copy-paste-in-urxvt

That said, on reading the docs I could find, I suspect the answer to my question is NO, but  I thought I should consult the collective wisdom of StackOverflow anyway, just in case.  So thanks for any advice (other than "GET USED TO IT, NOOB" which would not only be unhelpful, but also inaccurate)!

[Originally posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780489, but moved here.]